# Does the Colab PRO plan allow me to use the stabble diffusion webui?

Tags: google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

very good night. Google recently ended access to stable diffusion webui links for free on Google Colab. I would like to know if I pay for the Colab Pro plan, will I be able to use this service again, or will I have to purchase the Colab Pro+ plan? thank you in advance.

I used stable diffusion webui by Google Colab. Access to free accounts for this service has been terminated. If I pay for a plan, will I be able to use it again?